# Хитро достать данные из массива

Tags: php, symfony2

Ребят есть 2 Entity в Симфони2, надо достать данные из массива по такому правилу

```
/** @var array */
$priceSelected->getSelectedHotels()  
/** @var string */
$booking->getHotelCode()
/** @var array */
$priceSelected->getPrice()
```

если строка из booking есть в price, вернуть:

```
$priceSelected->getPrice()
```

где номер элемента в массиве `$priceSelected->getPrice()` == номеру элемента в массиве `$priceSelected->getSelectedHotels()`

Comment: в чем у вас проблемы?

Comment: смотрите, проверить наличие я могу, а вот достать по номеру элемента чот туплю как

`if(in_array($booking->getHotelCode(), $priceSelected->getSelectedHotels(),true))
        {

        }`

что в нутри этого писать хз

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-search.php эта функция вернет индекс, по нему в другом массиве возьмете

Comment: Ох, огромное спасибо. Детский затуп. Пойду кофе попью...